# Loading OPML(XML) file into TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, opml

I'm new with c# and I'm trying to load the content of a OPML file into a treeView  after a button click. I readed several tutorials about `System.Windows.Form.TreeView` and `System.Xml`, did many research, but i'm still unable to transfom the opml file into a treeview. I have this code that returns an error, someone can help me please?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.Load("C:\\subscription.opml");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Feeds"));
            LoadNode(xd.SelectNodes("//outline), treeView1.Nodes[0]);
        }
        private void LoadNode(XmlNodeList xmlNodes, TreeNode trvParent)
        {               
            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodes)
            {    
                TreeNode trnNewNode = new TreeNode(xmlNode.Attributes["text"].Value); //error: the exeption nullReference is not managed...
                    if (xmlNode.Attributes["text"] != null)
                        trnNewNode.Tag = xmlNode.Attributes["text"].Value;
                    trnNewNode.Expand();
                    trvParent.Nodes.Add(trnNewNode);
                    LoadNode(xmlNode.ChildNodes, trnNewNode);    
            }    
        }
```

Here is the content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<opml version="1.1">
<head>
    <title>My Subscriptions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <outline text="Catégorie1" >
        <outline text="Sience" >
            <outline text="Science Signaling" xmlUrl="http://stke.sciencemag.org/rss/current.xml" htmlUrl="http://stke.sciencemag.org/" description="Science Signaling, the Signal Transduction Knowledge Environment" language="en" type="RSS" />
        </outline>
        <outline text="Sport" >
            <outline text="L&apos;Equipe.fr Actu Golf" xmlUrl="http://www.lequipe.fr/rss/actu_rss_Golf.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.lequipe.fr" description="L&apos;Equipe.fr, Toute l&apos;actualité du golf" type="RSS" />
            <outline text="L&apos;Equipe.fr Actu Rallye" xmlUrl="http://www.lequipe.fr/rss/actu_rss_Rallye.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.lequipe.fr" description="L&apos;Equipe.fr, Toute l&apos;actualité des rallyes" type="RSS" />
        </outline>
    </outline>
    <outline text="Catégorie2" >
        <outline text="economy" >
            <outline text="Business Daily" xmlUrl="http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/worldservice/bizdaily/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p002vsxs" description="Examining the big issues facing the global economy, Business Daily demystifies the world of money. From giant industries like aviation and automotive to the smallest scale start-up, Business Daily asks the big questions about free trade, technology and investment. There is also analysis of management and marketing trends, and what business jargon really means - together with reports on business news from around the world via the BBC&apos;s global network of reporters." type="RSS" />
            <outline text="Business &#38; Economy Coverage | PBS NewsHour Podcast | PBS" xmlUrl="http://www.pbs.org/newshour/rss/podcast_business.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.pbs.org/newshour/topic/business/" description="The latest news, analysis and reporting about Business &#38; Economy from the PBS NewsHour and its website, the feed is updated periodically with interviews, background reports and updates to put the news in a larger context." type="RSS" />
        </outline>
        <outline text="politic" >
            <outline text="Power and Politics with Evan Solomon from the 
CBC News Network (Highlights)" xmlUrl="http://www.cbc.ca/podcasting/includes/powerandpolitics.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.cbc.ca/podcasting" description="Get daily access to the movers and shakers when Evan interviews the country&apos;s most influential figures. From politicians to writers to leaders from all parts of the country." type="RSS" />
            <outline text="Politics Weekly" xmlUrl="http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/series/politicsweekly/podcast.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.guardian.co.uk/audio" description="Political analysis from the Guardian and Observer&apos;s top journalists and commentators" type="RSS" />
        </outline>
    </outline>
</body>
</opml>
```

Here is what i want to show in treeView:

> ```
>    -Categorie1
>       -sience
>          Sience Signaling
>       -sport
>          L'Equipe.fr Actu Golf
>          L'Equipe.fr Actu Rally
>    -Categorie2
>       -economy
>          Business Daily
>          Business &#38; Economy Coverage | PBS NewsHour Podcast | PBS
>       -politic
>          Power and Politics with Evan Solomon from the...
>          Politics Weekly
> ```

Hope someone can help! Thanks.

Comment: does this help you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317597 ?